# TSQL - Select Count(*) ..into Varchar variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

let's say I have 10 tables and I need to write a simple LOG entry that states how many records each tables has.

Something like

```
Declare @msg Varchar(MAX)
Set @msg = 'Process Succeeded; Table1 has xx record, Table2 has zz records, Table3 has ww records ...'

Insert INTO LOG (msg) VALUES (@msg)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Or roll it up into:

```
 declare @Summary as VarChar(256)
 select @Summary =
   'Foo: ' + Cast( ( select Count(42) from Foo ) as VarChar(10) ) +
   ', Bar: ' + Cast( ( select Count(42) from Bar) as VarChar(10) )
 select @Summary
```

Answer (score 2):

Since SQL Server currently does not have any support for something like `string.Format`, you have to do:

```
DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @Table1Count INT
SELECT @Table1Count = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Table1 

DECLARE @Table2Count INT
SELECT @Table2Count = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Table2

..... and so forth for each table you want to consider

SET @msg = 'Process Succeeded; ' + 
    'Table1 has ' + CAST(@Table1Count AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' rows, ' + 
    'Table2 has ' + CAST(@Table2Count AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' rows...' + ........

Insert INTO LOG (msg) VALUES (@msg)
```

Right now, in SQL Server, this is a pain - that's why it might be a lot easier to just return those counts to a front-end app and do the formatting and log writing there.

[SQL Server 2012 will have a `FORMAT` function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/samvangassql/2011/11/29/new-string-function-in-sql-server-2012-_1320_-format_28002900_/) (long overdue!)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Declare @msg Varchar(2000) 
,@table1count varchar (100) 
,@table2count varchar (100) 

Select @table1count= cast(count(*) as varchar (100)) from table1

Select @table2count= cast(count(*) as varchar (100)) from table2

Set @msg = 'Process Succeeded; Table1 has '+@table1count +' records, Table2 has '+@table2count+' records, ...' 

 Insert INTO LOG (msg) VALUES (@msg)
```

Of course I only gave you the first two tables, you can use teh same techinique for the rest.

Comment: WOW! How **big** are your tables if you need a `varchar(100)` to hold their count?!?! :-)

Comment: I was just teasing with that. Sort of my response to the orginal varchar (Max)

Comment: in fact ..i'm still laughing about that (hehe)